# Java looping to find object in arraylist cant get past index[0]

Tags: java

I got an issue, I have to check in a for loop if an object already exists in the arraylist. When the object doesnt exist I have to create one/add one. However I cant find a way to check this, because he will always just check the first index and then shut down, or he will check the first index and the objects wont match, thus I create 3 duplicate objects before the loop realises there is a duplicate its too late. Here is the code:

I really hope u guys can help I just cant get the solution.

```
    Klas klas = informatieSysteem.getKlasVanStudent(student);         // klascode van de student opzoeken
    for (Les l : informatieSysteem.deLessen) {
        if (l.getKlas().getKlasCode().contains(klas.getKlasCode()) && l.getStartTijdString().contains(begintijd) && l.getEindTijdString().contains(eindtijd) && l.getDateString().contains(datum) && l.getKlas().getStudentenKlas().contains(student)) {
            System.out.println(l);
            les = l;
        }
    }
    if (student.getAbsentie().size() == 0) {
        student.addabsentie(datum, begintijd, eindtijd, les, student);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < student.getAbsentie().size(); i++) {//anders controle of dit object voorkomt in lijst.
            Absentie ab = student.getAbsentie().get(i);
            System.out.println(student.getAbsentie().size());
            if(student.getAbsentie().listIterator().next().getLes().equals(les)){
            //if ((ab.getLes().getDateString().equals(les.getDateString()))&& (ab.getLes().getStartTijdString().equals(les.getStartTijdString()))&&ab.getLes().getEindTijdString().equals(les.getEindTijdString())) {
                System.out.println("niet else");
            }else{
                student.addabsentie(datum, begintijd, eindtijd, les, student);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    JsonArrayBuilder jab = Json.createArrayBuilder();
    for(Absentie ab: student.getAbsentie()) {
                                // Uiteindelijk gaat er een array...
        jab.add(ab.getLes().getDateString());
    }
    conversation.sendJSONMessage(jab.build().toString());                       // terug naar de Polymer-GUI!
}
```

Comment: You might want to use a `Set` instead of `ArrayList`. Then you don't have to check whether the object exists or not, there will never be duplicates. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: Use `for (Absentie ab : student.getAbsentie())` I don't get what the listIterator is doing in the code. It's kinda hard to read. Maybe you should refactor and clean it up first.

Comment: is the `les` variable set in `equals(les)`? Where?

Comment: Absentie has an object Les, and Les propertys I the only way to check if it already exists

Comment: Gotta format the code and clean it up - can't help you when reading the code makes me dizzy. Just a friendly requst -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding of your question,

You are trying to add `Absentie` instances to your `ArrayList` (present in the `Student` instance). And, to avoid duplicates, you are trying to check if that particular instance already exists.

`ArrayList` has a `contains` method defined for it, so there is no need for you to loop through it and check it like that. The `contains` method calls the `equals` method defined in the object to match a given record. So, you just have to make sure you `override` the `equals` method in the `Absentie` class and compare with a field which would satisfy the constraint.

```
    class Absentie{
        ...
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Absentie absentie){
            //Define your equality condition here
        }
    }
```

When trying to check if the array already contains.

```
    Absentie absenties = student.getAbsentie();
    if(!absenties.contains(absentie){
        student.addAbsentie(absentie);
    }
```

Also, you are not supposed to use `Iterators` like that. Please refer to documentation to understand how they should be used.

Comment: Oh I have been so foolish, I dont know whats wrong with me